# How achieve a two line Prompt?

Tags: powershell, prompt

In the batch language of Microsoft's CMD.EXE console window, I never liked having my command start at the far right, after a long display of the directory path. So in my *Control Panel → System → Advanced System Settings → Environment Variables* I saved the following assignment, where `$_` is like a Soft Return:

```
PROMPT=[$P\]$_$+$G$S
```

The displayed prompt was two lines like this:

```
[C:\Temp\]
>
```

(The `$+` tracks `pushd` and `popd`, the fancier than `chdir` commands. `$S` is space. By the way, the `^` character a line wrap/continuation character in batch, just as backtick `` ` `` is in PowerShell.)

Now I want the same-ish two line prompt in PowerShell. There is good news and bad news.

The good news is I can achieve that in my open PowerShell window by typing at the `>` prompt:

```
 function prompt {'[' + $(get-location) + '\] SHIFTENTER > '
```

(By SHIFTENTER I mean press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, what I think might be called a "soft return"?)

....... BAD NEWS, PROBLEM ......

I want to put the above `function prompt ...` line into my profile PowerShell script, namely `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` (at path `$Profile`). But how?

Notepad.exe has no support for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

MS Word understands <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but when I SaveAs .txt, and then examine with Notepad++, I see a plain CR-LF (meaning \r\n, 0x0d 0x0a).

Notepad++ menu *Edit → Character Panel* enables me to insert special ASCII characters into my .txt / .ps1 file, such as 0x0b called VT (for "vertical tab"). But despite some claims on websites, VT is not behaving like a Soft Return when I use it in my `function prompt ...` profile .ps1 file (I also run the profile .ps1 script to retest).

Can the prompt I want be established by a profile .ps1 script?

Comment: So, how exactly it not work when your profile have plain CR-LF?

Comment: @PetSerAl, In my testing, a plain newline from a press of Enter does not translate to a newline in the prompt. Instead, I now see that [System.Environment]::NewLine added into the prompt string value solves the whole problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you found a solution yourself: please post it as an answer of your own. Do not edit a solution into your question.

Answer (score 18):

The PowerShell equivalent of your batch-prompt is:

```
function prompt { "[$(Get-Location)\]`r`n$("+"*(Get-Location -Stack).Count)>" }

#`r`n is just a shorter way of writing [System.Environment]::NewLine
```

Add it to the profile to suits your needs:

> **AllUsersAllHosts:**
>
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
>
> **AllUsersPowerShell:**
>
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
>
> **AllUsersISE:**
>
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
>
> **CurrentUserAllHosts:**
>
> C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
>
> **CurrentUserPowerShell:**
>
> C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
>
> **CurrentUserISE:**
>
> C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1

Comment: You must set encoding to UTF-16 LE because that's what Powershell expects for its profile file (UTF-8 encoding will not work)

Comment: Can you explain what $("+"*(Get-Location -Stack) does? Plus one for an elegant solution, just want to understand it better. Willing to read up if you can provide a hint at what its about. Thanks

Comment: It adds a plus-sign per location in the stack (saved locations after changing directory using `Push-Location`). So `>` would be nothing, `++>` would mean you have two locations available in the stack to return to using `Pop-Location`

Comment: Do you know how i can make this work with `posh-git`? It seems to disable loading extensions

Comment: I added on AllUsersAllHosts and I got . : ```File C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1 cannot be
loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more
information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
+ . 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1'
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess```